# How do you Describe a Geometry where the Christoffel Symbols Vanish?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

In a follow up to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611236/), we can prove that there are two components to acceleration in Newton's Second Law of Motion thusly,
$$U^{\mu}=\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d \tau}$$$$U=U^{\mu}e_{\mu}=U^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}=\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d \tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}=\frac{d}{d\tau}$$
$$\nabla_{\nu}f=\partial_{\nu}f$$$$\nabla_{\nu}(U^{\lambda})=\partial_{\nu}U^{\lambda}$$
$$\nabla_{V}U=\nabla_{V^{\rho}e_{\rho}}U=V^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}U$$

Now we are ready to derive the full expression of the 4-force:
$$F=m \nabla_{U}U=m U^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}U=m U^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}(U^{\mu}e_{\mu})=m[ U^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}(U^{\mu})e_{\mu}+U^{\nu}U^{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}(e_{\mu})]=m[ U^{\nu}(\partial_{\nu}U^{\mu})e_{\mu}+U^{\nu}U^{\mu}\Gamma^{\sigma}_{\nu \mu}e_{\sigma}]=m[ U^{\nu}(\partial_{\nu}U^{\mu})e_{\mu}+U^{\nu}U^{\sigma}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \sigma}e_{\mu}]=m[ U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}U^{\mu}+U^{\nu}U^{\sigma}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \sigma}]e_{\mu}=m\left[ \frac{dU^{\mu}}{d \tau}+U^{\nu}U^{\sigma}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \sigma}\right]e_{\mu}$$
Since obviously $F=F^{\mu}e_{\mu}$ we can write the equation using just the components:
$$F^{\mu}=m\left[ \frac{dU^{\mu}}{d \tau}+U^{\nu}U^{\sigma}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \sigma}\right]$$
$$a\equiv\frac{dU^\mu}{d\tau}$$$$A\equiv U^\nu U^\sigma\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \sigma}$$
$$F=m\left( a+A\right)$$

So we apparently assume that, locally, we can just forget about the inertial acceleration - that the Christoffel symbols vanish because there is no detectable curvature - and evaluate the force as:
$$F=m a$$

I've been using the term "Locally flat" to describe a geometry where the Christoff Symbols can be ignored, but I've been getting push back from several directions, so:

**What is the proper terminology for what we're doing when we just assume that the Christoff Symbols vanish within the scope of our measurements?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper terminology for what we're doing when we just assume that the Christoff Symbols vanish within the scope of our measurements?

You are using a “locally inertial” coordinate chart. It has nothing to do with the curvature of the spacetime geometry and is simply a choice of coordinates. There are specific constructions called “normal coordinates”.

Comment: I may have things backwards.  I understand now that the local geometry of spacetime is flat.  You can always construct a set of coordinates **at a point** that act like a Lorentz frame.  So is it fair to say that studies of galaxy rotation curves assume that the **global curvature** of the universe is zero?  I've yet to find a study that includes a consideration of a globally curved universe.

Comment: I don’t know enough about the analysis of galactic rotation curves to answer that. Probably that should be a separate full question, but I won’t be able to answer

Comment: Is it fair to say that most Cosmologists today consider the universe to be **globally flat**.  Or, at least, flat on the scale of a galaxy or galaxy cluster?

Comment: @Gluon Soup you have to be careful what they are talking about. The current concordance model is spatially flat, but spacetime is curved. When you are talking about curvature in general then the latter quantity is assumed. But specifically in cosmology they may be talking about the spatial curvature.

Comment: I understand that spacetime is curved in the neighborhood of energy/momentum.  I'm now attempting to understand what it means to be **globally flat**.  If I measure the separation vector between two test particles as they pass through Andromeda, I will detect curvature of spacetime in that neighborhood.  If I remove all the extra energy/mass (leaving just average density of matter/energy) from the neighborhood of M31, then perform the same experiment, do you expect to see any acceleration in the separation vector?  If there is none, can I assume that spacetime is globally flat?

Comment: For global flatness you need a vacuum solution.  Even something like the concordance cosmology spacetime is not globally flat. Even an average density will have curvature (unless the cosmological constant exactly balances it)

Comment: If this universally understood by Cosmologists, then why isn't the global curvature included in any analysis of galaxy rotation curves, galaxy clusters or gravity lensing?  I've been through many, many papers over the years and not once seen someone even attempt to add a parameter for the global curvature as a placeholder.

Comment: I don’t know enough about the analysis of galactic rotation curves to answer that. Probably that should be a separate full question, but I won’t be able to answer

Answer (score 8):

> So we apparently assume that, locally, we can just forget about the inertial acceleration - that the Christoffel symbols vanish because there is no detectable curvature - and evaluate the force as $F=ma$.

No, that's not true.  Whether the Christoffel symbols vanish **at a point** is purely a matter of coordinates.  If you choose a curvilinear coordinate system, then the Christoffel symbols will generally be nonzero everywhere even in the complete absence of curvature.  If you choose e.g. rotating coordinates, then the Christoffel symbols will encode the centrifugal pseudo-force.

We can always choose coordinates such that the Christoffel symbols vanish at an arbitrary point $x_0$ of our choosing, but the presence of spacetime curvature means that they will *not* vanish in a nonzero neighborhood of $x_0$.  The best we can do is choose Riemann normal coordinates, in which case
$$\Gamma^{i}_{jk}(x) =\frac{1}{3}(R^i{}_{j\ell k}+R^i{}_{k\ell j})(x^\ell - x_0^\ell)$$
Restricting our attention to a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x_0$ means that we can make the Christoffel symbols small, but in general they cannot be ignored (except at the origin, where they vanish).

> Yes, there is. If you use the formula I gave above, F=m(a+A) on spiral galaxies and galaxy clusters, then there is no need for Dark Matter. The fact that Cosmologists assume there are no Christoffels when they construct velocity curves indicates that between the solar system and Andromeda, you've completely forgotten that intergalactic space can be curved.

Yikes.  This is way off the mark.  I'm not sure what you think dark matter is or how you think velocity curves are constructed, but I would suggest that you not kick off your study of GR by assuming that an entire field of physics whose modern theory is **completely** rooted in relativity has "forgotten" about the its most elementary implications.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119721/discussion-on-answer-by-j-murray-how-do-you-describe-a-geometry-where-the-chris).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If you are considering GR to be a gauge theory, then you are choosing a gauge (all manifolds are locally flat, meaning there always exists such a choice by the way). If this choice of coordinates can be made globally, then it also follows you're working in either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or Minkowski space of appropriate dimension (which you are in is determined by your signature).

In math literature you might hear this choice referred to as a "local trivialization (of the tangent bundle).

In other contexts you'll hear such coordinates referred to as locally inertial coordinates.

The real key, however, is that the (local) vanishing of the Christoffel symbols is a statement about the *coordinates* you're using, not about the spacetime you're working on. The only time you end up with an assumption about the spacetime itself is if you assume there is a single coordinate system such that the Christoffel symbols vanish everywhere. This statement "locally flat" that you refer to is true of all manifolds. Essentially this follows from the definition of a manifold (a collection of charts from some space which map into subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or Minkowski). This can also be seen as equivalent to the statement that there always exist coordinates such that the metric is flat (diagonal with appropriate signature) at a given point (but such a choice cannot always be made globally). In fact, this is essentially the basis of frame fields (usually called veirbeins or tetrads in GR contexts), which you seem to allude to with some of your notation.

**Edit:** As a general comment I should also say that really the Lagrangian formulation of dynamics is the best way to approach the question "what are the equations of motion."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119698/discussion-on-answer-by-richard-myers-how-do-you-describe-a-geometry-where-the-c).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a curved space. In **geodesic coordinates**, the Christoffel symbols vanish, **at a point**, *although the derivatives of those symbols do not vanish*. (d'Inverno. Introducing Einstein's Relativity. page 77-78)

> I've been using the term "Locally flat" to describe a geometry where the Christoff Symbols can be ignored,

The Christoffel symbols can be non-0 in flat space. Consider polar coordinates. Polar coordinates are flat.

Christoffel symbols alone are not a measure of flatness of a space. The measure of curvature is The Riemann Tensor.

$\Gamma= 0$ everywhere $\implies {R^a}_{bcd}=0$

(d'Inverno. page 80)

$\Gamma= 0$ at a point $\implies {R^a}_{bcd}=$ something that involves only derivatives of $\Gamma$.

(d'Inverno. page 145)

So, you can make $\Gamma=0$ at a point in a curved space where ${R^a}_{bcd}\not=0$.

And that's useful. You can use $\Gamma=0$ to study curved spaces, at a point.

[Susskind on Christoffel symbols and geodesic coordinates.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyW0LWEACfI)

Comment: *The derivatives of the Christoffel symbols are related to the flatness of space*  I've seen references to this, but haven't seen a concrete example.  Can you explain more about that and/or given an example?

Comment: The Riemann Tensor. It involves $\Gamma$ and its derivatives.

Comment: The name of the book’s author is d’Inverno, not d’Invernio.